# Street Address as separate lines

Tags: data-loader, npsp

I'm are preparing data to be imported from our current Excel database to Salesforce.

Our organisation stores address of each member/contact in Excel as separate lines rather than a block of address in a single cell. So the columns are Street Line 1, Street Line 2, City, State, Postal Code, Country.

I noticed that Mailing Street in Salesforce is a text box where you can store multiple lines of street address.

How should I go about storing those multiple lines of address as separate lines using the NPSP Data Import CSV Template in Excel since I can only see one column i.e. Home Street?

It is very important for us to store each line separately since we use certain types of reports in Excel to filter out results based on certain line number of street address.

Comment: You can create custom field to store street data separately.

Comment: Until I know, SalesForce has only one field for Street. There are some ways to solve this issue. One is mentioned, creating custom fields. Also, you could create a "standard" to store the address using like special char, but you could have some issues. I already had this issue and I created a new field (Brazil needs a separated field for House Number, to issue invoice - legal requeriment).

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use the single Street field in Salesforce.  You will run into many headaches if you try to use a custom field to maintain a separate second line for address.

In your Excel file, you should concatenate the two Street columns into a single column.  I recommend using the `CHAR(10)` in your concatenation formula so you'll have a line break separating the first and second lines of the address.